# any UML tools for Scala

Tags: scala, uml

Is there any UML tools available for Scala. the reason for my question is that its a blend of functional and OO concepts hence I would like to know how such tools denote functions in UML diagrams.

Answer (score 23):

This [thread](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Recommendation-for-UML-class-diagram-modeling-td1936798.html) summarizes the obstacles faced by any UML tool wanting to represent Scala classes:

> - there is no official representation of mixins in UML
> - it is difficult to represent:
>
>   - closures
>   - Scala type members
>   - class constructor parameter bounds (a.k.a. "template
>       type" bounds/constraints)
>   - covariant and contravariant class constructor inheritance
>   - the relationship between a class or trait and the
>       companion object

---

This thesis ("[Evaluierung des Einsatzes von Scala bei der Entwicklung für die Android-Plattform](https://github.com/meiko/tribosmap/raw/master/MRachimowDiplA.pdf)", pdf, German) does add stereotypes for trait mixins and other scala specific elements (pp. 146).

What was added by **Meiko Rachimow** in 2009:

## attributes, getter and setter

[image: Scala attributes]

> For all published attributes exist implicit getter (`attribute1` and `attribute2`), except the visibility was declared as `private` (`attribute3`). If published attributes are tagged with a stereotype `Var`, they are variables, for which there exist implicit setter (`attribute2`). The stereotype `lazy` marks instance variables as lazy (`attribute4`).

## classes and generics

[image: Scala class and genericity]

> Like in UML, generic classes are marked with an abstract type. By using the Scala language syntax, upper and lower bounds can be declared for this type (`EineKlasse`). It is possible to use structured types as bounds, which attributes and methods are embraced by curly braces (`EineKlasse2`). Generic type parameters of methods are embraced by square brackets (`operation`).

## traits

[image: Scala traits in UML]

> Traits are displayed like abstract classes and tagged with the stereotype `trait`. Abstract attributes and methods are displayed in italics (`attribute2`, `operation2`). For abstract attributes the dependency arrow can be tagged with the stereotype `requires` (`Trait3`, `attribute3`). On the other hand, the stereotype `self` is used for self referencing types (`Trait4`). If a trait inherits another trait, the inheritance is displayed with an inheritance arrow (`Trait2`). This arrow type is used too, if a class extends a trait (`Klasse`). To emphasis the “mix in” of traits, the inheritance arrow can be tagged with the stereotype `mixin` (`Klasse`).

## singleton objects

[image: Scala singleton in UML]

> Singleton objects are displayed like classes and tagged with the stereotype `singleton`. It is possible, that there exist two class elements with the same name. In fact it is a singleton object with the belonging companion class. In this case  the dependency arrow is tagged with the stereotype `hasA`.

Comment: @PeterSchmitz: I have fixed the link to that PDF file.

Comment: @VonC It would really help me ( and may be others) if you can add scala signatures (or skeletons ) for the traits class diagram. (e.g. `trait Trait2 extends Trait` and so on. )

Comment: @VonC The translation is terrible (parts are wrong). I will fix this the next days... maybe 5 years too late... Who is Meike Massimow?

Comment: @Meiko Sure, I will appreciate the edit. Sorry for the botched name.

Answer (score 2):

You could try (experimental) **[Dia2Scala](https://github.com/mnn/Dia2Scala)** tool. [Notation](https://github.com/mnn/Dia2Scala/blob/master/other/Notation.md) used by this code generator is based on a notation from Meiko Rachimow's thesis (described in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7817723/1017211) from VonC).

Comment: It looks promising . But can it generate diagram from code?

Comment: @Wei-ChingLin Nope, it's only one way tool: dia -> scala. Writing a Scala parser could be quite difficult I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested the [Green UML Eclipse plugin](http://green.sourceforge.net/). Some months ago it didn't work but with the Scala IDE nightly version Apr 2012) you can get some sort of class diagram. Looks promissing.

Answer (score 1):

The tool I use is the same for Java, the UML diagram (classes or dependencies) in Intellij however its only available for "Ultimate" users

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram.html